# Error when deploying Next.js app to Firebase: Error: Could not find a production build in the '/frontend/.next' directory

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to deploy my next.js app for my frontend application. I am deploying my app to firebase. My frontend code is written in react. So all my pages are .tsx files. The starting point of the application is index.tsx . All the code is located in the frontend directory. This is my project file structure:

```
peno-entrepreneurship-3d-oclusion/
└── frontend/
    ├── .firebase/
    ├── .next/
    ├── .yarn/
    ├── functions/
    │   ├── index.js
    │   ├── package.json
    │   └── package-lock.json
    ├── node_modules/
    ├── out/
    ├── public/
    │   ├── 3d-teeth.jpg
    │   └── delete-icon.png
    ├── src/
    │   ├── components/
    │   ├── gen/
    │   │   └── proto/
    │   │       └── threedoclusion/
    │   │           └── v1/
    │   ├── hooks/
    │   ├── pages/
    │   │   ├── api/
    │   │   ├── _app.tsx
    │   │   ├── _document.tsx
    │   │   ├── client.tsx
    │   │   ├── contact.tsx
    │   │   ├── download-scan.tsx
    │   │   ├── index.tsx
    │   │   ├── landing-page.tsx
    │   │   ├── login-page.tsx
    │   │   ├── newwaitreal.tsx
    │   │   ├── patient.tsx
    │   │   ├── register-page.tsx
    │   │   ├── scans-page.tsx
    │   │   ├── test-vr.tsx
    │   │   ├── test.tsx
    │   │   ├── upload-page.tsx
    │   │   └── wait.tsx
    │   ├── resourcesVR/
    │   ├── styles/
    │   ├── firebase.js
    │   ├── react-app-env.d.ts
    │   └── tsconfig.json
    ├── .env
    ├── .eslintrc.json
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── .nvmrc
    ├── .prettierignore
    ├── .prettierrc
    ├── .yarnrc.yml
    ├── README.md
    ├── next.config.js
    ├── package.json
    ├── tsconfig.json
    ├── weg.json
    ├── yarn.lock
    ├── firebase.json
    ├── package.json
    └── package-lock.json
```

When running this command: `sudo firebase deploy --only hosting --project relu-backend` I got this error in the logs of google cloud:

```
{
  "textPayload": "Function execution took 3485 ms, finished with status: 'crash'",
  "insertId": "329pgcf6s8va4",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "nextApp",
      "region": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "relu-backend"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-04-26T12:32:22.404524570Z",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "0ijgi821jkw4"
  },
  "logName": "projects/relu-backend/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/relu-backend/traces/4957ef55996650eb1ad72d81a198e99d",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-04-26T12:32:22.588632286Z"
}
```

And this is the main error:

```
{
  "textPayload": "Error: Could not find a production build in the '/frontend/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id\n    at NextNodeServer.getBuildId (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:352:23)\n    at new Server (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:146:29)\n    at new NextNodeServer (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:166:9)\n    at NextServer.createServer (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:167:24)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    at async /workspace/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:187:31\n    at async /workspace/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:95:40",
  "insertId": "644919d60009392bfc4d88a1",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "relu-backend",
      "region": "us-central1",
      "function_name": "nextApp"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-04-26T12:32:22.604459Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "instance_id": "00c61b117ce1fbf12f8d6c5dac36e84f63de071cdabbdfee9725b0caa57ba1656d00beb5361dcb0b10cb5ab4afcb72d116e6d323beb8a7467884",
    "execution_id": "0ijgq5scgie1"
  },
  "logName": "projects/relu-backend/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/relu-backend/traces/c03cb868d219257f693160fd507f04f6",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-04-26T12:32:22.925283285Z"
}
```

When building and running my application locally, everything works perfectly. So I think the problem is with the deployment to firebase. I think the problem is with this line: `const app = next({ dev, conf: { distDir: "../../frontend/.next" } });` but I have tried so many things already and I keep getting the same error.
Here is some extra information from my config files.

**`firebase.json` file:**

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "runtime": "nodejs16"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/_next/static/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "public, max-age=31536000, immutable"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/_next/:path*",
        "destination": "/_next/:path*"
      },
      {
        "source": "/api/:path*",
        "destination": "/api/:path*"
      },
      {
        "source": "/:path*",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nextApp"
      }
    ],
    "predeploy": [
      "yarn build"
    ]
  }
}
```

**`package.json` file in my frontend directory:**

```
{
  "name": "threedoclusion",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.4.1",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "yarn build-frontend && yarn build-functions",
    "build-frontend": "next build",
    "build-functions": "cd functions && yarn build",
    "export": "next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format": "npx prettier --write ."
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "functions"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@bufbuild/connect-query": "^0.1.0",
    "@bufbuild/connect-web": "^0.8.1",
    "@bufbuild/protobuf": "^1.0.0",
    "@firebase/storage": "^0.11.2",
    "@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "@next/font": "13.1.6",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.24.10",
    "@types/downloadjs": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/three": "^0.149.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "v5.2.3",
    "build": "^0.1.4",
    "cannon-es": "^0.20.0",
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "eslint": "8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.6",
    "file-saver": "~2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^9.20.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "grpc-tools": "^1.12.4",
    "grpc-web": "^1.4.2",
    "grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts": "^5.3.3",
    "next": "^13.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.0",
    "three": "^0.150.1",
    "yup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@bufbuild/buf": "^1.15.0-1",
    "@bufbuild/protoc-gen-connect-es": "^0.8.1",
    "@bufbuild/protoc-gen-connect-query": "^0.1.0",
    "@bufbuild/protoc-gen-es": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/ccapture.js": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/node": "18.14.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "@types/three": "^0.149.0",
    "@types/webxr": "^0.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "typescript": "4.9.5",
    "unplugin-obj": "^0.1.2"
  }
}
```

**`package.json` file in my functions directory:**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build ../../frontend && firebase deploy --only functions --project relu-backend"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.7.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1",
    "next": "^13.3.1"
  }
}
```

**`index.js` file in my functions directory:**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev, conf: { distDir: "../../frontend/.next" } });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

exports.nextApp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return handle(req, res);
});
```

These files are in my .next directory, so I think my production build is correct:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:frontend dagmalstaf$ ls -la .next
total 1072
drwxr-xr-x  16 root        staff     512 Apr 26 14:31 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 27 dagmalstaf  staff     864 Apr 26 14:27 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root        staff      21 Apr 26 14:31 BUILD_ID
-rw-r--r--   1 root        staff    6922 Apr 26 14:31 build-manifest.json
drwxr-xr-x   6 root        staff     192 Apr 26 14:31 cache
-rw-r--r--   1 root        staff      93 Apr 26 14:31 export-marker.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root        staff     511 Apr 26 14:31 images-manifest.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root        staff   96778 Apr 26 14:31 next-server.js.nft.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root        staff      20 Apr 26 14:31 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root        staff     312 Apr 26 14:31 prerender-manifest.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root        staff       2 Apr 26 14:31 react-loadable-manifest.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root        staff    3003 Apr 26 14:31 required-server-files.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root        staff    1702 Apr 26 14:31 routes-manifest.json
drwxr-xr-x  13 root        staff     416 Apr 26 14:31 server
drwxr-xr-x   6 root        staff     192 Apr 26 14:31 static
-rw-r--r--   1 root        staff  367011 Apr 26 14:31 trace
```

Anyone who knows how to fix this error? Would be greatly appreciated since I already spent many many hours on this. It's my first time deploying a next.js app to firebase, so all help is appreciated !

Comment: I've just started getting an error about not having a "pages" directory today.  Nothing changed in my config from the last successful deployment, and everything works locally too.